# Creating DVD navigation using VLC versoin 1.1.4

Tags: vlc, dvd, libvlc

I have been developing a DVD player using vlc version 1.1.1 libraries and have recently upgraded to version 1.1.4.  Previously I have been getting the current vlc_object_t by using libvlc_get_vlc_instance and then using the object, along with the relevant key information, in subsequent calls to __var_SetInteger.

This method worked fine for version 1.1.1 but in version 1.1.4 libvlc_get_vlc_instance no longer exists. Does anyone know of the replacement method or of another way to handle DVD menu navigation?

Comment: looks like you solved it http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=83835&p=277027&hilit=libvlc_get_vlc_instance#p277027

Comment: To a degree I have, as I just went back to 1.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VLC_PUBLIC_API void libvlc_media_player_navigate(libvlc_media_player_t* p_mi, unsigned navigate);`

is the new DVD menu navigation method. It is within the libvlc_media_player header. However, To my knowledge it has only been implemented in version 1.2 which is still in development. It is available from the VideoLan nightly builds website if you're feeling brave.

`var_SetInteger(vlc_object_t *p_obj, const char *psz_name, int64_t i)`

is still implemented in the vlc_variables header but vlc_object_t is no longer easily accessible as they have removed libvlc_get_vlc_instance as it was apparently a "hack"

> Remove libvlc_get_vlc_instance hack from libvlc 
>   http://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/vlc-devel/2010-January/072219.html

If anyone knows any differently please let me know.